# Multiple Django Admin Arguments with Extensions

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-extensions

Is there a way to use multiple Django extensions in the `admin.site.register()` inside admin.py? I'm using "simple-history" and "import-export" extensions, but I can only have one of them in the `admin.site.register()`.

Example: I have a model named, "Cars", that is using the "simple-history" extension so I need `admin.site.register(Cars, SimpleHistoryAdmin)`, as their documentation says it should. I want to use the import/export extension as well to the same "Cars" model, but the `admin.site.register()` doesn't take multiple arguments for me to add it.

**models.py**

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Make = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Car Table"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Make
```

**admin.py**

```
class CarResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = ('id','Year', 'Make', 'Model',)

class CarAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CarResource
    pass

#I want to use the import/export extension (code above), along with simple-history
admin.site.register(Cars, CarAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cars, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

I've tried using a proxy and inlines, but the proxy makes a new model which I don't want and when using inlines I get an error saying that it requires a foreign key, but I'm not trying to get the model objects from a different model. Naming them the same model doesn't work because the model is already registered. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, class can have more than one parent. Just inherit from 2 parents at once. But both `ImportExportModelAdmin` and `SimpleHistoryAdmin` are inheriting from ModelAdmin, that's not good. There is also `ImportExportMixin`, we can use it instead of `ImportExportModelAdmin`, so there will be only one reference to ModelAdmin.

```
class CarResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = ('id','Year', 'Make', 'Model',)

class CarAdmin(ImportExportMixin, SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    resource_class = CarResource
    pass

#I want to use the import/export extension (code above), along with simple-history
admin.site.register(Cars, CarAdmin)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for this answer. I should've read more on the import-export documentation. I didn't expect such a simple answer from this and I'm really grateful.